# Made an own DNS server, how to add photos to the host?

Tags: networking, dns

I made a DNS server using simple DNS, added a host (ip linked to domain). The site does open on chrome (I disconnected from my default DNS) but without photos. How do I fix that?

Comment: Please provide more information. Are the images beings served from the same IP? What have you tried already?

Comment: Let me change the question a bit. Is it fixable because i think that if I don't use the authoritative dns server of a specific site I added (It is a real site that i added just so I can enter it with my own DNS).

Comment: Please answer the following question. Are the images being served from the same server?

Comment: Found a solution, need to host another server for the images, thanks any way!